# Accomodate a database for multiple users

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, authentication

Not entirely sure how to phrase this, but in essence I am trying to implement some login/user functionality so each user can log their OWN collection of cards, rather than being able to log in and see  EVERYONE'S cards. etc

Would asp.net Identity be best suited for this? if so could someone advise a smart method based on my models and such below:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Atk { get; set; }
    public int? Def { get; set; }
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public virtual List<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Deck { get; set; }


}

public class Deck
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Card")]
    public virtual List<Card> Card { get; set; }
}

public class DeckCardViewModel
{
    public Card Cards { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
}
```

Target behaviour:

New user registers and logs in
they add cards to their collection and create decks etc 
ANOTHER new user registers and logs in
they add cards to their collection COMPLETELY Independent of any other users data tables

e.g, like how we can all log into gmail but can't view eachothers emails.

Rough idea of how to do this, is to create another model that contains both Card and Deck models, then users can log in, and add cards, but those cards will only be added to a table mapped to their ID?

Not sure how to go about this, and as you can probably tell i'm having a hard time phrasing my question, making it just as difficult to know exactly what to google to help my problem.

resources very much welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this:

1. At the database level using row level security (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Set filtering using the `WHERE` clause in SQL.

e.g

```
var userCards = await _context.Cards.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: ahh amazing, thanks!, would you reccond building a dummy database before I make any changes to my current one? this is all for practice